# XMLWorker doesn't see img (itextsharp)

Tags: c#, itext, xmlworker

I parse HTML to PDF using XMLWorker. And I've got problem with images. When in the path of tag  between words are located spaces  or Cyrillic symbols are in the path, that images from HTML don't adding to PDF. For solving problem with spaces I used `path.Replase(" ", "%20")` and `path.Replase(" ", "+")`, but it doesn't helping.

Should I convert path of img to base64 and after use ImageProvider (AbstractImageProvider) like [here](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker-itext5/html-images)?

If path is without spaces or Cyrillic symbols, that XMLWorker parse HMTL is  right.

```
<img src="D:\c#\PdfItextSharp\HTML_to_PDF_book\HTML_to_PDF_book\bin\Debug\Data\Resources\Documentation\IASO\Modules\LearningFrame\Images\32x32-tree_add_subitem.png" class="icon">
```

But if there are in path that symbols, that images don't add to pdf

```
<img src="D:\c#\PdfItextSharp\HTML to PDF book\HTML to PDF book\bin\Debug\Data\Resources\Documentation\IASO\Modules\LearningFrame\Images\32x32-tree_add_subitem.png" class="icon">
```

or

```
\\HI-PC\AllUsers\Выгрузка\DebugHtmlToPdf\User manual - Instructor\bin\Data\Data\Screenshots\0e39c7d5-4489-4d8b-ae84-ee85a2e225ee.jpg
```

How I can so

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: @mkl, I added it.

Comment: But those aren't *URLs*, those are *file system paths*. According to the HTML specification: "The src attribute must be present, and must contain a valid non-empty URL potentially surrounded by spaces referencing a non-interactive, optionally animated, image resource that is neither paged nor scripted."

Comment: @mkl, what do you suggest to me? What should I use in c# for convert to "According to the HTML specification"?

Comment: [This msdn blog entry](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2006/12/06/file-uris-in-windows/) might help you along

Comment: @mkl, will XMLWorker understanding path whit Cyrillic symbols?

Comment: First of all a path with Cyrillic symbols also must be made an actual URI. Whether that suffices or not, I do not know, I have not tested anything like that yet.

Comment: Are you using an old version of XML Worker?? I can successfully create a PDF with images that have a symbol (`c#`) in the path, **and also** Cyrillic characters in a UNC path. (`\\path\Выгрузка`)

Comment: @mkl - this is great timing....in a funny sort of way. I just got done fixing an issue with UNC paths used exactly the same way as the OP in a web application. Some versions of Internet Explorer transparently '_convert_' UNC paths to the correct file URI scheme, and allow users to access whatever file type the UNC path points too. Unfortunately, this is quite common in Intranet scenarios.

Comment: @kuujinbo funny indeed. But I doubt it makes sense to try and change XmlWorker to understand all Microsoft'isms used in MS intranet applications. If I remember correctly their CRM html alone already was horrible...

Comment: @kuujinbo, I use iTextSharp 5.5.11 => XmlWorker 5.5.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For solving it problem I used next code. Thanks [mkl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1729265/mkl) for his helping.

```
var uri = new System.Uri(tmpPath);
var convertedURI = uri.AbsoluteUri;
```